# How to pass var to next view in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want pass url to detail view controller to display in webview but it gives excess bad error  on targetController.url=url;

if i am doing this way then its going to next view perfectly but not as first given

```
NSString*url=@"www.google.com"; 

PortfolioDetailViewController *targetViewController=[[PortfolioDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PortfolioDetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
targetViewController.stringURLToLoad =url;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:targetViewController animated:YES];
[targetViewController release];
```

error log

```
2012-01-05 10:25:21.459 MotherAndChildGuide[656:207] http://www.stbcouncil.com
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

(gdb)
```

Comment: Your problem is not in this code. Either something is wrong with `url1` or in your PortfolioDetailViewController.

Comment: its not going to detail view controller it gives on line targetViewController.url=url not moving to detail controller

Comment: How `url1` is defined? Do you have an instance variable `url` in PortfolioViewController?..and what is the stacktrace of your error?

Comment: yes i have declared url1 in header class and it gets value from xml and error is exc bad error

Answer (score 0):

In Actual Class

```
- (IBAction)tappedItemAtIndexButton:(id)sender
{
  NSString *url =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"www.google.com"];
  PortfolioDetailViewController *targetViewController=[[PortfolioDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PortfolioDetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
 targetViewController.url=url;
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:targetViewController animated:YES];
 [targetViewController release];

 }
```

In Target class you need to use 
.h

```
NSString *url;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *url;
```

.m

```
@synthesize url;
```

and use that string anywhere in that class

and also use

```
  NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:self.url]];
 [webView loadRequest:request];
```

for loading in  webview

Comment: r u using property in target class?

Comment: r u used the
 NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:self.url]];
[webView loadRequest:request];

or not

Comment: i will use NSURLREquest after reaching target view controller but it crashes before reaching while assigning

Comment: Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned you wish to pass a var (a URL )to next view controller and load something in web view. You can declare a Var to hold the incoming value in your **PortfolioDetailViewController** such as

either   `NSString* strURLToLoad;` or  else    `NSURL * urlToLoad;`

and expose them by making ***property*** .In both of these situation you need to pass the correct value from your previous viewcontroller as

```
 - (IBAction)tappedItemAtIndexButton:(id)sender {

      NSString*url =url1;
      PortfolioDetailViewController *targetViewController=[[PortfolioDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PortfolioDetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
     targetViewController.strURLToLoad = url;
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:targetViewController animated:YES];
     [targetViewController release];

     }
```

or as

```
     - (IBAction)tappedItemAtIndexButton:(id)sender {

         NSURL* urlToSend = [NSURL urlWithString:url1];
          PortfolioDetailViewController *targetViewController=[[PortfolioDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PortfolioDetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
         targetViewController.urlToLoad = urlToSend;
         [self.navigationController pushViewController:targetViewController animated:YES];
         [targetViewController release];

         }
```

depending on what type of variable have you declared in your **PortfolioDetailViewController**

In case you pass a string from previous view controller you will need to use it as something like

```
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:self.strURLToLoad]];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

or else in case you pass a URL you can directly load it using

```
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: self.urlToLoad];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”. when i assign

Comment: Enable NSZombie in your project and please put the crash log.. That will be be quite helpful to assist you resolve the crash.

Comment: I make you clear i  am getting url string value from xml file it saves in url1 when i use url1 one to targetController it gives error

Comment: @Jogi as per your edited question description there seems to be issues with the url in line targetController.url=url;. Where and how do you set value in this var i.e url. Try to retain the value in url and then use targetController.url = url;